# excluding a directory from accurev using pop command

Tags: accurev

I have 10 directories in a AccuRev depot and don't want to populate one directory using "accurev pop" command. Is there any way? .acignore is not suiting to my requirements because in another jenkins build I need that folder. Just want to save time to avoid unnecessary populate of directories.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Answer (score 1):

I would create a stream off this stream and exclude the directories you dont want.  Then you can pop this stream and only get the directories you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the AccuRev populate command you can specify which directories to populate by specifying the directory name:

accurev pop -O -R *thisDirectory*

will cause the contents of  *thisDirectory* to match the backing stream from the time of the last AccuRev update in that workspace.

The -O is for over write and the -R is for recurse. If you have active work in progress the -O will cause that work to be over written/destroyed.

The .acignore is only for (external) files and not those that are being managed by AccuRev.

David Howland